# Unable to assign a value in LightSwitch 2012 project

Tags: lightswitch-2012

I'm trying to implement the following code into a LightSwitch 2012 project.  I'm getting an error when I try to assign the this.ExpenseReport to a value.  The error reads "Property or indexer 'LightSwitchApplication.ExpenseReportDetails.ExpenseReport' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only".

```
partial void ExpenseReportDetails_InitializeDataWorkspace(List<IDataService> saveChangesTo)
    {

        // Write your code here.
        if (this.ExpenseReportId == -1) // -1 means new Report    
        {        // Create a new ExpenseReport        
            this.ExpenseReport = new ExpenseReport();
        }
        else
        {
            // Get existing Expense Report        
            this.ExpenseReport = this.DataWorkspace.ApplicationData.ExpenseReports_SingleOrDefault(this.ExpenseReportId);

            // Set the name of the Tab to the default field on the Entity        
            this.SetDisplayNameFromEntity(this.ExpenseReport);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of `ExpenseReport` does not have a `set` property, only a `get` propery. THis means that you can not run the following line:

```
this.ExpenseReport = this.DataWorkspace.ApplicationData.ExpenseReports_SingleOrDefault(this.ExpenseReportId);
```

Can you change `ExpenseReport` to be writable?

Comment: I'm not seeing one.  I'm using this code so that when a user selects a record the info will be used to open an ExpenseReportDetails screen.